# Is there a command for macOSX terminal(CMD) to pause a script, open a NEW terminal, and resume?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I am trying to find a method to combine two scripts so that they can be run in one go. However, it would be useful if both scripts still ran in separate windows as I need to look through the logs for certain bits of information. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have X11 installed (e.g. [XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)), you can run your scripts in new xterm windows:

```
xterm -e ./scriptA.sh & xterm -e ./scriptB.sh &
```

But if you want to use the default OSX Terminal.app, this should work:

```
open -a Terminal.app ./scriptA.sh; open -a Terminal.app ./scriptB.sh
```

I tried passing arguments to the scripts using the `--args` parameter to `open`, but for some reason it didn't work for me.

#### Update

The more OSX idiomatic way to do this is seems to be to start Terminal.app from an Applescript snippet with the osascript command:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"scriptA.sh <args>\""
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"scriptB.sh <args>\""
```

The quotes are escaped so you can e.g. do variable expansions from the calling bash for the script args.

Comment: Isn't the Mac terminal simply named Terminal? But you should be able to launch that similarly to how `xterm` is launched here.

Comment: My apologies, I am very much a Mac noob. I learned quite a lot for it very quickly and I'm still trying to fill in the terminology gaps. I recieved -bash: xterm: command not found

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I think X11 is no longer installed by default.  I must have installed [XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) at some point.  So for an OSX-specific answer, `open -a Terminal.app` can be used.

Comment: @user3444100 Sorry, you probably want to use `Terminal.app` instead of `xterm`.  So my edit.

Comment: @Digital I'm afraid the open -a Terminal.app goes through but has no effect. Should it launch a second terminal window?

Comment: @user3444100 Did you give the script name (with path) as a parameter after "open -a Terminal.app" ?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma My fault.... I did not. The perks of being new to this! I will report back soon.

Comment: I think I may have mis-stated the question, or it isn't properly executing. I am looking for a solution that will do what this achieves, but also start running each script in the respective windows. I am getting some odd error though, I will share it with you all tomorrow. Thank you for the effort thus far!

Comment: @user3444100 One more edit - hopefully it works for you this time.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I did finally manage to get this working. I aprpecaite the aid!

Comment: @user3444100 What was the fix for you?  Should this answer be accepted? :)